# What is an easy way to break an NSArray with 4000+ objects in it into multiple arrays with 30 objects each?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsarray

What is an easy way to break an NSArray with 4000 objects in it into multiple arrays with 30 objects each?

So right now I have an NSArray *stuff where [stuff count] = 4133.

I want to make a new array that holds arrays of 30 objects. What is a good way to loop through, breaking *stuff into new 30-object arrays, and placing them inside of a larger array?

Obviously the last array won't have 30 in it (it will have the remainder) but I need to handle that correctly.

Make sense? Let me know if there is an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Off the top of my head, something like (untested):

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfArrays = [NSMutableArray array];

int itemsRemaining = [stuff count];
int j = 0;

while(itemsRemaining) {
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(j, MIN(30, itemsRemaining));
    NSArray *subarray = [stuff subarrayWithRange:range];
    [arrayOfArrays addObject:subarray];
    itemsRemaining-=range.length;
    j+=range.length;
}
```

The `MIN(30, i)` takes care of that last array that won't necessarily have 30 items in it.

Comment: I like your approach with the MIN(30, i). Very clean. I'll use this, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
            NSMutableArray *arrayOfArrays = [NSMutableArray array];
            int batchSize = 30;

            for(int j = 0; j < [stuff count]; j += batchSize) {

                NSArray *subarray = [stuff subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(j, MIN(batchSize, [stuff count] - j))];
                [arrayOfArrays addObject:subarray];
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Converted the answer of @samvermette to **SWIFT 3**

```
        var arrayOfArraySlices = [ArraySlice<CBOrder>]() // array of array slices

        var itemsRemaining = orderArray.count
        var j = 0

        while itemsRemaining > 0 {
            let range = NSRange(location: j, length: min(20, itemsRemaining));
            let arraySlice = orderArray[range.location..<range.location + range.length]
            arrayOfArraySlices.append(arraySlice)
            itemsRemaining -= range.length;
            j += range.length;
        }
```