# split NSArray in groups of smaller NSArrays for paging

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have an `NSArray` of say 100 `NSManagedObjects` and I need to split that into an `NSArray` that contains 10 `NSArray` objects that each hold 10 of theses `NSManagedObjects`, how would I accomplish that?

I am going to do some paging and this will work well for me.

Comment: Assuming you just would like to pass in an array and have the same code work every time, why not just pass it an NSRange of length 10 and position [whichever], along with the original unmodified NSArray, and have the code for a page work based on the NSRange, instead of absolute index?

Comment: That sounds perfect - how do I accomplish that?

Comment: This is almost an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852012/what-is-an-easy-way-to-break-an-nsarray-with-4000-objects-in-it-into-multiple-ar. The answer was to use `subArrayWithRange:` repeatedly, with a shifting range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines should work instead of breaking it into separate arrays

```
//make a new range for each page
NSRange myRange = NSMakeRange(10, 10);
NSArray * myArray = [NSArray array];

//...pass both into a function
for (int i = myRange.location; i < myRange.location + myRange.length; i++) {
    //stuff with the array elements
    [[myArray objectAtIndex:i] doSomething];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

How are you getting these `NSManagedObjects`? If you're using an `NSFetchRequest`, you may want to keep that around and only get 10 results at a time from it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my code:

[object splitArrayWithArray:arrayWith100Objects rangeNumber:10];

```
- (NSArray*) splitArrayWithArray:(NSArray*)rawArray rangeNumber:(int)rangeNumber{
    int totalCount = rawArray.count;
    int currentIndex = 0;

    NSMutableArray* splitArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    while (currentIndex<totalCount) {
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(currentIndex, MIN(rangeNumber, totalCount-currentIndex));
        NSArray* subArray = [rawArray subarrayWithRange:range];
        [splitArray addObject:subArray];
        currentIndex +=rangeNumber;
    }
    return splitArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's no one-liner, but this will split an array into pages:

```
NSArray *arrayToSplit = ...

int pageSize = 50;
NSMutableArray *arrayOfPages = [NSMutableArray new];

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, pageSize);

while (range.location < arrayToSplit.count) {
    if (range.location + range.length >= arrayToSplit.count)
        range.length = arrayToSplit.count - range.location;

    [arrayOfPages addObject:[arrayToSplit objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range]]];

    range.location += range.length;
}
```