# Split an NSArray into multiple arrays randomly

Tags: cocoa, nsarray

I have an array of string elements like this [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O]

I want to split this into *n* arrays, where *n* is chosen randomly, and the elements in each new array are also chosen randomly.

For example if n=4, and the original array is [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O], I might get

```
[C,E,G,A]
[I,B,O,L]
[H,F,J,N]
[D,K,M]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want your sub arrays to have same number of elements inside them? Or, do you want to have x number of arrays where each of them can have variable number of elements inside them?

Comment: Hello nayem, yes i want to have same number of elements inside them.

Comment: Well, you should first `shuffle` your original array ( follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/56656/3687801) ) and then you have to `split` your `shuffled array` ( follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6852105/3687801) )

Comment: thx. its working fine.